# Get first and last name from active directory using username (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap

I wanna get first and last name from active directory using only username. Below code works but doesn't show anything for the user who doesn't have last name. I need this to show only the first name for the ones who don't have last name.

Does anybody have any idea?

```
Private Function GetActiveDirUserDetails(ByVal userid As String) As String
    Dim dirEntry As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
    Dim dirSearcher As System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    Dim domainName As String = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName
    Try
        dirEntry = New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & domainName)
        dirSearcher = New System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)
        dirSearcher.Filter = "(samAccountName=" & userid & ")"

        dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("GivenName")
        'Users e-mail address
        dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn")
        'Users last name
        Dim sr As SearchResult = dirSearcher.FindOne()
        If sr Is Nothing Then 'return false if user isn't found 
            Return False
        End If
        Dim de As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = sr.GetDirectoryEntry()
        Dim userFirstLastName = de.Properties("sn").Value.ToString() + ", " + de.Properties("GivenName").Value.ToString()
        Return userFirstLastName
    Catch ex As Exception ' return false if exception occurs 
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
End Function
```

**EDIT**

I found the solution, it's very simple tho..

```
Private Function GetActiveDirUserDetails(ByVal username As String) As String
        Dim dirEntry As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
        Dim dirSearcher As System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
        Try
            dirEntry = New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://172.17.25.10:389/DC=bsidomain,DC=com")
            dirSearcher = New System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)
            dirSearcher.Filter = "(samAccountName=" & username & ")"
            dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("GivenName")
            dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn")
            Dim sr As DirectoryServices.SearchResult = dirSearcher.FindOne()
            If sr Is Nothing Then
                Return False
            End If

            Dim de As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = sr.GetDirectoryEntry()

            Dim ObjFirstName As String = ""
            Dim ObjLastName As String = String.Empty

            Try
                ObjFirstName = de.Properties("GivenName").Value.ToString()
                ObjLastName = de.Properties("sn").Value.ToString()

            Catch ex As Exception
                ObjFirstName = de.Properties("DisplayName").Value.ToString()
            End Try

        MsgBox(ObjFirstName + ObjLastName)

        Catch ex As Exception ' return false if exception occurs 
            Return ex.Message
        End Try
    End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried it like this here and it worked:

```
Dim de As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = sr.GetDirectoryEntry()
Dim userFirstName = de.Properties("GivenName").Value.ToString()
Dim userLastName = de.Properties("sn").Value.ToString()
Return userFirstName + ", " + userLastName
```

Comment: Thanks! But it is still not working for me I dont know why

Answer (score 1):

You could try this format

```
''' other code removed for brevity
Dim de As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = sr.GetDirectoryEntry()
Dim names = New List(Of String)
If de.Properties("sn") <> Nothing AndAlso _
    de.Properties("sn").Value <> Nothing AndAlso _
    String.IsNullOrEmpty(de.Properties("sn").Value.ToString()) = False Then
    names.Add(de.Properties("sn").Value.ToString())
End If
If de.Properties("GivenName") <> Nothing AndAlso _  
    de.Properties("GivenName").Value <> Nothing AndAlso _
    String.IsNullOrEmpty(de.Properties("sn").Value.ToString()) = False Then
    names.Add(de.Properties("GivenName").Value.ToString())
End If
Dim userFirstLastName = String.Join(", ", names)
Return userFirstLastName
```

Comment: I got error using this : in function(s) it says expression expected

Comment: @C.PurS minor syntax snafu. I fixed it.

Comment: @C.PurS the reason your current code isnt working is because when constructing a string, if any of the parts is Nothing, then the entire expression becomes Nothing.

Comment: Function(s) is still giving an error? Did you Import `System.Linq`

Comment: do you mean System.Data.Linq? If yes, then I already import it. But when I try to import System.Linq it gives me this warning: system,linq does not contain any public member. And the funtion(s) is still giving me error

Comment: What version of VB.Net are you using?

Comment: That little piece of information would have been nice to know a lot earlier. I'll edit